# await in nested for ... of loop

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
  async traverse(url) {
    const ts = new TournamentScraper()
    const ms = new MatchScraper()
    const results = []
    const tournaments = await ts.run(url)
    for(let href of tournaments.map(t => t.href)){
      let matches = await ms.run(href)
      let pages = ms.getPages()
      let seasons = ms.getSeasons()
      //console.log(pages)
      //console.log(seasons)
      results.push(matches)
      for(let href of pages) {
        //console.log(href)
        matches = await ms.run(href)
        //console.log(matches)
        results.push(matches)
      }
    }

    return results
  }
```

TournamentScraper returns an array of objects, which typically looks like this:

```
{name: 'Foo', href: 'www.example.org/tournaments/foo/'}
```

The link points to the tournament's last season's first page. This page contains the links to the other seasons and a paginator (if any).

MatchScraper's run returns some data, and sets the instance's dom property. `getPages()` and `getSeasons()` consumes this property and each returns an array of links.

The problem that results contains only the first batch of matches. I can see the 2nd page's matches in the console log, but they are not in the results array when `traverse` returns.

I found this [rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop) which is against await in for loop. The problem, that I have to wait for `ms.run(href)`, because it sets dom, and `getPages()` and `getSeasons()` needs it to be set, to extract the needed links.

Comment: you could put the nested for loops in a function, and call await on the function

Comment: At first: your code should work fine. Secondly: dont listen to others concerning coding style. Do it your way...

Comment: The eslint rule is about a possible performance optimisation, not a mistake. The code should work with a plain `await`. If you are getting all the `matches` in the logs, but in the `results` array despite pushing them immediately after logging, something else must be going on here.

Comment: "_dont listen to others concerning coding style. Do it your way_" That's some pretty terrible advice in my opinion.

Comment: the reason for the eslint rule is that putting await statements in for loops delays each loop iteration until the entire asynchronous operation completes - making it act as a synchronous operation

Comment: @realseanp putting await in for loop does make the code run slower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work. It utilizes Promise all rather than for loops

```
const run = href => ms.run(href);

async function getMatches(href) {  
  const out = [];
  const matches = await run(href);
  const pages = ms.getPages();

  out.push(matches);

  if(pages.length) {
    const pageResults = await Promise.all(pages.map(href => run(href)));
    out.push(...pageResults);
  }

  return out;
}

async function traverse(url) {
  const ts = new TournamentScraper();
  const ms = new MatchScraper();
  const tournaments = await ts.run(url)
  const matches = await Promise.all(tournaments.map(t => getMatches(t.href)));
  return matches.reduce((a, b) => { 
    a.push(...b);
    return a;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to wrap the await statements in a try/catch just in case there's an error